# why doesn't TreeDataProvider exist in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I followed this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/yocode to create a vscode plugin project in `javascript`. I want to use `TreeDataProvider` to create a tree view but this class is not found from `vscode` module.

```
const { TreeItemCollapsibleState, TreeDataProvider } = require('vscode');
```

The above code return `undefined` to `TreeDataProvider`. Below is my package.json dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.42",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.43",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "vscode": "^1.1.17"
  }
```

Does anyone know how to require this class in a javascript project?

Comment: Have you run `npm install` to let vscode download and install the latest typings file? I use the tree data provider with vscode 1.1.17 without problems.

Comment: Yes,  I have run `npm install` and the plugin can be run The only issue I have is can't find `TreeDataProvider`. What else do I need to add into the dependencies?

Comment: Nothing else is required. See my extension code for an example: https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/ImportsProvider.ts

Comment: Is it because I am using javascript not typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a very late answer, but I just stumbled upon this today.

`TreeDataProvider` is an `interface`, not a `class`, which means:

- your class `implements` (TypeScript syntax!) and not `extends` it,
- it only exists in TS and, like all other type information, is not preserved after being transpiled to JavaScript.

To implement this interface in JS, you just have to implement its methods. Here's what they look like in TS:

```js
// T is the type of your element (of course irrelevant in JS)
getTreeItem(element: T): vscode.TreeItem | Thenable<vscode.TreeItem>
getChildren(element: T): vscode.ProviderResult<T[]>
// optionally:
onDidChangeTreeData?: vscode.Event<void | T| T[] | null | undefined> | undefined;
```

The `TreeDataProvider` interface is just there to make it easier to write an implementation that is full and proper.